# Accessing Spotify Metadata API from within a Spotify app?

Tags: spotify

I want to run Spotify searches from within a Spotify app (to find tracks for an artist, for which I do not have a Spotify URI, only the name).

I have not found functionality in the App API to run searches. An alternative is to talk to `ws.spotify.com` to get to Spotify's search, but these web services do not support jsonp which is required for their use in a Spotify app.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not the finest way to solve your problem. There is a direct API for searching within your app. See Juan's solution.**

But you could also talk to ws.spotify.com directly when you add the domain to your app's manifest.json.

`"RequiredPermissions": ["http://ws.spotify.com" ]`

e.g. http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=kaizers+orchestra, see their
[Developer Site](http://developer.spotify.com/en/metadata-api/overview). The response contains the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *", so you should be able to query from within your app.

Comment: While it would work, the answer by Juan seems a better way to do it

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sp.core.search`

```
sp.core.search("query",
    {onSuccess: function(result) {
        // parse result
        }
    }
);
```

`sp.core.getMetadata` if you have the uri

```
    sp.core.getMetadata("uri", {
        onSuccess: function(data){
            console.debug(data);
        },
        onFailure: function(){
                //...
        },
    });
```