# Can the cocoalibspotify metatdata methods be used without a Spotify account?

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

This appears to have been last addressed a year ago here:
[Accessing Spotify Metadata API from within a Spotify app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408581/accessing-spotify-metadata-api-from-within-a-spotify-app)

It seems that the cocoalibspotify API has been worked on a lot since then, but can someone confirm that we still have to fall back to using the [Spotify web API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/) in iOS for users without Spotify accounts to be able to search and view metadata for albums and artists?

Everything appears to work when a user is logged via the API (using [SPSession attemptLoginWithUserName]), but when doing for example, [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded] on an SPTrack, it times out unless you're logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for CocoaLibSpotify to work at all, you need to have a logged-in user. The Web API is the only way to access metadata without this.